# Is it possible to boot into a different recovery from TWRP?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot

Normally I boot into TWRP with

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

Is it possible, after I boot into TWRP with the above command, to boot into a different version of TWRP (from a different image) without booting into a rom, enabling ADB debugging, booting into the bootloader, and then running the command above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reboot to Bootloader from TWRP.

- Using either the `Reboot` menu and clicking on `Bootloader`
- Or from `adb shell` when TWRP is running using `twrp reboot bootloader`

From the bootloader, `fastboot` will work and you can run

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```